# Can we make this more terse with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I am curious if there is a way where I can capture the lower lines (the creation of the dictionary and loop to add values) in the linq statement itself. Right now the select new returns a new anonymous type but I am wondering if there is a way to make it return a Dictionary with all the values pre-populated.

```
    XDocument reader = XDocument.Load("sl.config");
    var configValues = from s in reader.Descendants("add") select new { Key = s.Attribute("key").Value, s.Attribute("value").Value };

    Dictionary<string, string> Settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var s in configValues)
    {
        Settings.Add(s.Key, s.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) extension method.

```
 XDocument reader = XDocument.Load("sl.config");
 var Settings = reader.Descendants("add")
   .ToDictionary(s => s.Attribute("key").Value, s => s.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Comment: It should be `Dictionary<string, string> Settings =` rather than `var configValues =`

Answer (score 2):

```
var = XDocument.Load("sl.config").Descendants("add").ToDictionary
    (x => x.Attribute("key"). Value, x => x.Attribute("value"). Value);
```